# JavaScript polling wrapper / module. Request for code quality analysis

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, polling

I have written a small JavaScript function which will perform an Ajax request every x amount of seconds.

I was hoping some of you could give it a look over and give me any pointers on redundant code or bad practice.

The idea of the function is to:
1) Allow for polling to be initiated
2) Once initiated, poll once every x seconds and perform an ajax request.
3) Stop polling once disablePolling() is run.

Here is the code:

**requester.js**

```
function Request() {

this.poll = false;

this.activatePoll = function () {
    this.poll = true;
    this.runPoll();
};

this.disablePoll = function () {
    this.poll = false;
};

this.runPoll = function () {
    var self = this;
    var poll = setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: './request.php',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function () {
                if (self.poll == false) {
                    clearTimeout(poll);
                } else {
                    self.runPoll();
                }
            }
        })
    }, 1000);
};
}
```

For anyone else which wants to run the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Requester</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Requester</h1>
<div id="requester">
    <input type="button" onclick="$request.test();" value="test">
    <input type="button" onclick="$request.activatePoll();" value="poll">
    <input type="button" onclick="$request.disablePoll();" value="turn off poll">
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/request.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $request = new Request();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

**request.php**

```
<?php
echo json_encode($time());
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Better suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the power to move posts, please just click 'edit' and copy paste the code over to codereview yourself, thanks.